Cloud rendering issue, Car is blurry and I can't figure out why
I am rendering this animation on garage farm as my m1 Mac is too slow. The animation renders fine on my computer but every time I upload it to a cloud render the car seems to disappear in a blur.
I have tried doing it with motion blur off, baking the animation, etc but it always comes out with a car that is ghosting in and out like a mist.
Any thoughts on how to fix this?



Would it be possible to upload a blend file? That might make it easier for us to track down the problem.

Sure thing, I put it in this google drive folder:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mv1cPerTqzOsIfn8889Xvc-bukU_qCA3?usp=sharing

Before rendering the full animation, do you try a single frame ?

it works fine for me except there's a glitch on the light of the car

It works fine in blender locally on my Mac, the issue only occurs when I try to render the animation by uploading it to a cloud render farm.
I have tried two different cloud rendering services and they all return the same warped animation. I do try single frame rendering and it shows me this ghosting effects in the single frames.
Moonboots, did you render it just on your computer?

yes on my computer
